# How can I set the max height to a listview inside an AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an AsyncTask that configure several devices but, some of then can fail and when the task finishes trying to configure them all, it shows a AlertDialog with all the devices that fail. The problem is when a lot of devices fail because the listview gets so big that my dialog buttons disappear.

The code to create the dialog with the listView:

```
    if (listInitialSettingsAdapter.getNerasList("fail").size() != 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        ArrayList<ScanResult> listFailedNeras = listInitialSettingsAdapter.getNerasList("fail");
        ArrayList<String> listFailedNerasString = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ScanResult neras :
                listFailedNeras) {
            listFailedNerasString.add(neras.SSID);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listFailedNerasString);
        ListView listView = new ListView(activity);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dialog.setView(listView)
                .setTitle("Neras não configurados")
                .setMessage("Os Neras listados abaixo não foram configurados, deseja tentar novamente?")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(arrayAdapter, 0, null)
                .setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        InstalacaoInicialActivity.configureNerasTask = new ConfigureNerasTask(activity, listInitialSettingsAdapter.getNerasList("fail"), user, wifi, hashMapTimeZone, handler, showMeasures, listInitialSettingsAdapter);
                        InstalacaoInicialActivity.configureNerasTask.execute();
                        listInitialSettingsAdapter.updateViewWhenTryToConfigAgain(listInitialSettingsAdapter.getNerasList("fail"));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NÂO", null)
                .show();
    }
```

What I want to do is very simple, I want to limit the listView's height and scroll inside it to see all the devices that fail and keep the dialog's button untouchables.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use a constraintlayout in which to indicate the maximum height of the list, and attach the buttons to the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why create a LinearLayout inside the ConstraintLayout? Can I just add the ConstraintLayout with the list and buttons?

Comment: Of course, the user just had a question how to put the buttons on the ListView

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. What is the maximum height of the ListView here?